# ¿Como proteger rutas con jwt laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Hola basicamente implemente jwt en mi aplicacion laravel 10 la verdad que todo pareciera estar bien ya que el token se genera correctamente, asi como el metodo me parace funcionar correctamente ya que si accedo al mismo me trae los datos del usuario logeado. De momento esto es lo que llevo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $request->validated();

        try {
            if ($token = JWTAuth::attempt($user)) {
                // Autenticación exitosa, el token es válido
                return response()->json(compact('token'));
            }
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => 'Credenciales inválidas'
            ], 400);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // Error al crear el token
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error server',
                'msg' => 'No se pudo crear el token'
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    ////:: cerrar sesion ::////

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {

        /* Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect()->to('/login'); */

        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);

    }
}
```

Ahora la cuestion es que eh intentado proteger las rutas para esto cree un middleware donde tengo esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;

class JWTMiddleware
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        try {

            JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'msg' => 'token invalido'
                ], 401);
            }

            if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'expired',
                    'msg' => 'token expirado'
                ], 401);
            }

            return Redirect::route('error-401');


        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Finalmente la ruta protegida que coloque en web.php es la siguiente:

```
Route::middleware(['jwt.verify'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
});
```

El problema es que se supone estoy generando el token, estoy obteniendo los datos del usuario logueado con su metodo `me()` al parecer la autentificacion se realiza de manera correcta entonces por que no puedo acceder a la ruta protegida siempre me manda a mi url de error 401. No se ¿Que me falta o en que me equivoque?

Por ultimo esto tengo en api.php para generar las rutas de autentificacion

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

/* Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
 */

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});




Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => '/auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
 //   Route::post('refresh', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\AuthController::class, 'refresh'])->name('refresh');
   Route::post('me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->name('me');
});
```

Comment: No sé si sea el único error, pero tienes puesto `auntheticate` donde debiera ser `authenticate`. Luego la excepción termina en la vista de error 401 sin ser un error de autorización

Comment: si ya corregi eso pero no so debe a eso el problema

Comment: no veo el error que te sale?

Comment: bueno el error es basicamente que aunque estoy generando el token no puedo entrar a las rutas protegidas. Segun el token deberia enviarse en el request pero no entiendo como se hace eso si se supone que al hacer login ya genero un token no. Probando con herramientas como postman entro a Authorization selecciono bearer token ingreso ahi su token y listo funciona pero en cambio en laravel no entiendo como se supone que deberia incluir el token en el request. Creo que por eso no puedo acceder a las rutas protegidas con JWT